# Logger.log(Date inside Cell) keeps defaulting to today's date (Google Apps Script)

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Here's what I want to do:

I want to take a date inside a cell, and then increment a RANDOM number of seconds (between 0 and 60 or something like that) to the Date() value inside the cell. I want to do this using Google Apps Script.

```
var dateRange = sheet.getRange(dateRow, dateCol);
var date = dateRange.getValue();

dateRange.setValue(Date(date + Math.random()));
dateRange.setValue(new Date()).setNumberFormat("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
```

After it sets the date to today's date for some reason?

```
Logger.log(Date(date)); // Outputs Todays Date..?
```

Is this a time zone conflict? I have the spreadsheet set to Pacific Time.

Comment: new Date() always returns todays date

Comment: In this``dateRange.setValue(Date(date + Math.random())); .... `date` is presumably an object and Math.random() returns a number so that's never going to work

Comment: Date().valueOf() or .getTime() returns milliseconds

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I thought that in your script, by `dateRange.setValue(new Date())`, the current date is put. I thought that this might be the reason of your issue. So, in your situation, how about the following modification?

#### From:

```
dateRange.setValue(Date(date + Math.random()));
dateRange.setValue(new Date()).setNumberFormat("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
```

#### To:

```
var newDate = date.getTime() + (Math.floor(Math.random() * 60) * 1000);
dateRange.setValue(new Date(newDate)).setNumberFormat("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
```

Comment: Wow this solves it!! Okay now I want to make it a little more random....is it possible to increment the number of seconds by a random number between 0 and 86400? I choose 86400 because that's how many seconds are in a day. I want to increment the seconds with a random number but not increment the day. Let me know if that's possible!

Comment: @William Toscano Thank you for replying. When you want to use the range from `0-60` to `0-86400` that the both units are the seconds, please modify `var newDate = date.getTime() + (Math.floor(Math.random() * 60) * 1000);` to `var newDate = date.getTime() + (Math.floor(Math.random() * 86400) * 1000);`. And, please test it again. If I misunderstood your additional question, I apologize.

Comment: @William Toscano Now I thought that in your situation, `Math.round` or `Math.ceil` might be suitable instead of `Math.floor`. So please modify this for your actual situation.

Comment: Your solution worked again! It looks like it works fine with Math.floor. Is it super necessary to change it? Appreciate your help.

Comment: @William Toscano Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. For example, about [`Math.floor`], when `Math.floor(Math.random() * 1)` is used, it's always `0`. `Math.ceil(Math.random() * 1)` is used, it's always `1`.. When `Math.round(Math.random() * 1)` is used, `0` or `1` are returned. I thought that for example, when both the maximum and minimum numbers are required to be included, `Math.round` might be suitable. If this was not useful information, I apologize.

Comment: So appreciated! Thank you for all of this information! It seems to work either way! Appreciate your help!

Comment: @William Toscano Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.